# PHP Split & join array into separate lines

Tags: php, arrays, string, join, split

I've have the following arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Bob 
                       [1] => Freddy 
                     ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => IT Dev 
                       [1] => Programmer 
                     ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 123 
                       [1] => 23423 
                     ) 
      )
```

I'm trying to join the arrays together so it would look like the following:

**Bob - IT Dev - 123**

**Freddy - Programmer - 23423**

I've been messing with implode functions but in all reality I have no idea how to achieve this in PHP

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Max

Answer (score 1):

If your array is called `$myArray`, then:

```
foreach ($myArray as $row)
{
  $string1 .= $row[0]."-";
  $string2 .= $row[1]."-";
}

echo $string1."<br>";
echo $string2."<br>";
```

Comment: ACTUALLY what if there were more than 2 arrays e.g. [0],[1],[2],[3] etc... is there away to loop through them?

Comment: would that be like 3 arrays inside 1 array? or 1 array inside 1 array inside 1 array? If you want, you can edit your answer with the new situation and ill take a look at it

Comment: @MaxThorley oh and if this answer is the one that worked for you, please accept is (with a green checkmark) so that future users know it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your array:

```
$array = array(
    array('Bob', 'Freddy'),
    array('IT Dev', 'Programmer'),
    array('123', '23423')
);
```

You'll have to loop through each array, to join them into a sentence.

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $data){
    foreach($data as $index => $value){
        if(!isset($result[$index]))
            $result[$index] = $value;
        else
            $result[$index] .= " - " . $value;
    }
}
```

Now if you `var_dump` the `$result`:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
        string(18) "Bob - IT Dev - 123"
    [1]=>
        string(27) "Freddy - Programmer - 23423"
}
```

If you want to access an individual sentence, you can do:

```
echo $result[0]; // Bob - IT Dev - 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use array_column and implode to get the output.

**Array:**

```
$arr = array(
    array('Bob', 'Freddy'),
    array('IT Dev', 'Programmer'),
    array('123', '23423')
);
```

**mechanism:**

```
echo implode(" - ", array_column($arr, 0)); //Bob - IT Dev - 123
echo implode(" - ", array_column($arr, 1)); //Freddy - Programmer - 23423
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two solid methods for you.  The first is a "variadic approach" (`... splat operator`) and the second is a classic foreach loop leveraging `array_column()`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e955343ec4d12c022776d50858a7c3a1c9c38228))

```
$array=[
    ['Bob','Freddy'],
    ['IT Dev','Programmer'],
    [123,23423]
];

// Use this to see that both methods are flexible and produce the same result,
// so long as all subarrays have equal length.
// If there are differences in length, depending where the hole is, the results
// between the two methods will vary slightly.
// (The 1st method best preserves the intended output structure.)
/*$array=[
    ['Bob','Freddy','Jane'],
    ['IT Dev','Programmer','Slacker'],
    [123,23423,0],
    ['more1','more2','more3']
];*/

// this one requires php5.6 or better
$imploded_columns=array_map(function(){return implode(' - ',func_get_args());},...$array);
var_export($imploded_columns);

echo "\n\n";
unset($imploded_columns);

// or you can go with a sub-php5.6 version:
foreach($array[0] as $k=>$v){
    $imploded_columns[]=implode(' - ',array_column($array,$k));
}
var_export($imploded_columns);
```

Output from both methods:

```
// variadic method
array (
  0 => 'Bob - IT Dev - 123',
  1 => 'Freddy - Programmer - 23423',
)

// foreach method
array (
  0 => 'Bob - IT Dev - 123',
  1 => 'Freddy - Programmer - 23423',
)
```